# Possible values of difference of 2 primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that for any even number $2k$, there exists primes $p, q$ such that $p-q = 2k$?

[Polignac's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) talks about having infinitely many consecutive primes whose difference is $2k$. This has not been proven or disproven.

This is a more general version of my question on the [possible value of prime gaps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359772/possible-values-of-prime-gaps).

---

Of course, the odd case is easily done.

Comment: More like a Goldbach's Conjecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, this is an open problem (makes Polignac seem really tough then, doesn't it?).

The sequence [A02483](https://oeis.org/A020483) of the OEIS tracks this in terms of $a(n) =$ the least $p$ such that $p + 2n = q$. On the page it mentions that this is merely conjectured.

In terms of a positive result, I am almost certain that [Chen's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem) stating that every even number can be written as either $p + q$ or $p + q_1q_2$ is attained by sieving methods both powerful enough and loose enough to also give that every even number can be written as either a difference of two primes or a difference of a prime and an almost-prime (or of an almost-prime and a prime). I think I've even seen this derived before.

This would come as a corollary of Polignac's conjecture or of the vastly stronger [Schinzel's hypothesis H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H), which is one of those conjectures that feels really far from reach to me. I suppose that it has been proved on average over function fields (I think), so perhaps that's hopeful. On the other hand, so has the Riemann Hypothesis.